# BigQuery command line tool returns different results

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a table in BigQuery which has one row:

[image]

[image]

But when we run a query using the command line tool (`bq query...`), it returns 2 rows, and they are identical:

[image]

Why are we getting different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've hit a bug in BigQuery. The destination table used by a cached query has an extra row, so when you hit the cache (as in your second example), you see the extra row in the output.

**EDIT**: We removed the corrupt table in your cache at the time of the original report, and we have also identified and fixed the bug that caused this issue in the first place.